# UIImageView "jump" animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, game-physics, uigravitybehavior

In Swift (without SpriteKit etc.) I've created a UIGravityBehavior for a picture which I actually want to jump if I click - like Flappy Bird but maybe a bit more smooth -and now I need to know how I can let my UIImageView look like it's jumping.